# Assembly format and structure of the code

Tags: assembly, formatting, goto

I am taking an assembly class, and the exams are coming, so I have to ask, what's the standard format and structure of the source code in a non-structural language like assembly (8086 specific)?
Currently I like to format the code like below, having everything that executes after a label in a new tab column and not using unnecessary labels that I will not use later.

```
code segment
    start:  
        mov ax,data
        mov ds,ax

        mov cx,2
        label1:
             mov dl,'a'
             mov ah,2
             int 21h 
             loop label1

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
code ends
```

But my professor is doing something that I find completely ridiculous. He formats the code like below, using unnecessary labels and not using tabs for the labels:

```
PRINT_HEX PROC 
    H1: MOV BP,SP
        MOV CX,4    
    H2: MOV BX,[BP+2] 
    H3: XOR DL,DL 
        PUSH CX
        MOV CX,4
    H4: SHL BX,1
        RCL DL,1  
    H5: LOOP H4  
        POP CX
    H6: CMP DL,9    
        JA GRAMMA   
        ADD DL,48   
        JMP H7  
    GRAMMA: ADD DL, 55 
    H7: MOV AH,2
        INT 21H
    H8: LOOP H3
    H9: RET
PRINT_HEX ENDP
```

Of course he obviously knows more than I about assembly but his way seems wrong to me.
What is the standard way of formatting code in languages with labels?

Comment: Indentation aside, personally, extraneous labels bug me too, especially so nonsensically named as in the latter code. Are you sure he is not just adding them so that he can refer to specific instructions easily while teaching?

Comment: There are many styles, just like in any other language (and the inevitable flame-wars which follow.) The most comment scheme is labels in the leftmost column with indented opcodes. Some assembler parsers enforce this convention. Your variant is certainly used as well, often combined with macro packages providing basic control structures. I must confess I've never seen anyone indiscriminately label every line before though

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson , no he is not referring to them later ,in the above code you cant see it clearly but he just puts them there to split code segments that do similar things , like if he had 3 lines that print a char he would had put these 3 lines together under a label.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ,i put another example of his code that you can see more clearly what he is doing .

Comment: Another possibility is that he is showing you the output from an assembler rather than his source file, or taking the assembler output and adding to it. To be fair, I'll bet the professor wishes you would proofread your writing.

Comment: That code looks like an automatic source code generated from a disassembler. Well... weirder than that, as a disassembler won't include unnecesary labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard style for writting assembly, as there aren't a single standard for writting in C. This said, I find your approach quite reasonable: loops inside the procedure are easily detectable, with the loop counter at the same level of the rest of the loop body, and a blank line to frame visually that code block.

For ancient code written in assembly for 8 bit computers, I've found many times this kind of writting:

```
code segment
start:  mov ax,data
        mov ds,ax

        mov cx,2
label1: mov dl,'a'
        mov ah,2
        int 21h 
        loop label1

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
code ends
```

I think that the tradition of putting labels starting at the first column goes from the time that assemblers were pretty simple programs that made some assumptions as where labels, instructions and operands should go. My first one, Hisoft DevPac for the ZX Spectrum, assumed that anything written at the first column is a label, and thus, it doesn't need the colon after the label itself. As there are a number of people that learned assembler at that time, they have continued writting it the same way they used to (myself included).

Comment: well, if it's for an 8 bit computer, they probably won't be using AX ;)